# Search reference in text (Create Loop in function)

Tags: vue.js, axios

I have a question I've been working with view for a while now and in a table I have a text formatted this way ... name of the book, name of the author, number of pages or name of the book, name of the edition, year of the edition, name of the author, number of pages. I want to make sure that when I move my mouse over the reference ([name of the book] or [name of the book, name of the edition, year of the edition]) the description is displayed after returning my api.  The way to find the reference with only the name of the book works but I don't know how to search on a single parameter or 3 in my function.

```js
getBiblio(biblio) {
    this.resultbiblio = biblio.split(/\s*,|$\s*/, 1)
    axios
        .get('../api/biblio/' + this.resultbiblio )
        .then(response => (this.biblio = response.data))
    },
```

biblio = Les Fables, Jean de la Fontaine, 1600
Now let's say that my data is biblio: L'avare, édition de poche, 2002, Molière, 1300 I would like to test if there is a reference to L'avare, if the answer is no then I cut the biblio data to form the sentence L'avare, édition de poche, 2002 and I test to see if there is a reference.

Comment: It is not completely clear what you are trying to achieve. Do you just want to split a string into comma delimited pieces ?

Comment: @IVOGELOV  in my fonction i want write this : ````getBiblio(biblio) {
      this.resultbiblio = biblio.split(/\s*,|$\s*/, 3)  
      this.result = array.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + '; ' + currentValue)
        axios
          .get('../api/biblio/' + this.result)
          .then(response => (this.biblio = response.data))
      },```

Comment: And what is preventing you from writing this ?

Comment: @IVOGELOV it doesn't work, so I cheated...there aren't many editions. I have replace ", edition," by ". edition." . My api receives for exemple resulbiblio = L'avare .édition de poche. 2002 and the api change ". edtion." in ", edition,"

Comment: I am still confused but I am glad you've found a solution.